# Create generic and dynamic component to replace standard component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-props, react-hoc

I have Tree component, which renders TreeItemsRenderer that draws TreeItem. Each of them are seperate components.
I need to accept dynamic component that replaces default TreeItem, and I need to have all default TreeItem props. (for ex: const CustomComponent extends TreeItem). Tree is used in many places in code. So it needs to be generic.

- I tried to get all properties from default TreeItem by creating generic type
  `D extends ITreeItemProps<T>`.
- `T` generic is for item type.
- All of autocompletion works from outside. Only error is on TreeItemRenderer component with rendering SelectedRowComponent.

here is my components (It may be illogical at some moments, because I deleted unneccesary stuff and simplified logic):

**Tree :**

```js
import { ITreeItemProps, ITreeItem } from "./types";
import TreeItemRenderer from "./TreeItemRenderer";

export interface ITreeProps<T, D extends ITreeItemProps<T>> {
    items: ITreeItem<T>[];
    getItemKey: (item: T) => string | number; 
    SelectedRowComponent?: React.ComponentType<D>;
    SelectedRowProps?: Partial<React.ComponentProps<ITreeProps<T, D>['SelectedRowComponent'] & {}>>;
    selected?: string | number;
}

export default function Tree<T, D extends ITreeItemProps<T>>(props: ITreeProps<T, D>){
    const {
        items,
        SelectedRowComponent,
        SelectedRowProps,
        getItemKey,
        selected,
    } = props;
    return <>
    <TreeItemRenderer 
        getItemKey={getItemKey}
        items={items}
        SelectedRowComponent={SelectedRowComponent}
        SelectedRowProps={SelectedRowProps}
        selected={selected}
    />
    </>
}
```

**TreeItemRenderer:**

```js
import { ITreeItemProps, ITreeItem } from "./types";
import TreeItem from './TreeItem';

export interface ITreeItemRenderer<T, D extends ITreeItemProps<T>>{
    getItemKey: (item: T) => string | number; 
    SelectedRowComponent?: React.ComponentType<D>
    SelectedRowProps?: Partial<React.ComponentProps<ITreeItemRenderer<T, D>['SelectedRowComponent'] & {}>>;
    items: ITreeItem<T>[];
    selected?: string | number;
}

export default function TreeItemRenderer<T, D extends ITreeItemProps<T>>(props: ITreeItemRenderer<T, D>){
    const {
        SelectedRowComponent,
        SelectedRowProps,
        items,
        selected,
        getItemKey,
    } = props;

    return <>
        {items.map((item) => {
            const key = getItemKey(item);
            const isSelected = key === selected;
            return <>
                {
                    isSelected ? 
                    <SelectedRowComponent 
                        {...SelectedRowProps}
                        item={item}
                        getItemKey={getItemKey}
                        isSelected
                    />
                    : <TreeItem 
                        item={item}
                        getItemKey={getItemKey}
                        isSelected
                    />
                }
            </>
        })}
    </>
}
```

**Types component:**

```js
export interface ITreeItemProps<T> {
    getItemKey: (item: T) => string | number; 
    isSelected: boolean;
    item: ITreeItem<T>;
}
export type ITreeItem<T> = T & {
    children: ITreeItem<T>[];
};
```

And my problem is in TreeItemRenderer on line 28

```
Type '(Partial<D> & { item: ITreeItem<T>; getItemKey: (item: T) => string | number; isSelected: true; }) | (Partial<D & { children?: ReactNode; }> & { ...; })' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & D & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type 'Partial<D> & { item: ITreeItem<T>; getItemKey: (item: T) => string | number; isSelected: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & D & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
    Type 'Partial<D> & { item: ITreeItem<T>; getItemKey: (item: T) => string | number; isSelected: true; }' is not assignable to type 'D'.
      'Partial<D> & { item: ITreeItem<T>; getItemKey: (item: T) => string | number; isSelected: true; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'D', but 'D' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ITreeItemProps<T>'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to illustrate how your code can break the types. There are literal types in typescript. And `D extends ITreeItemProps<T>` is assuming you can provide more specialized type of `ITreeItemProps<T>`:

```ts
/*
type ExtendedItemProps = {
    isSelected: false;
    getItemKey: (item: {}) => string | number;
    item: {
        children: ...[];
    };
}
*/
interface ExtendedItemProps extends ITreeItemProps<{}> {
  isSelected: false
}
```

This type is perfectly extending your `ITreeItemProps` but here:

```ts
<SelectedRowComponent 
    {...SelectedRowProps}
    item={item}
    getItemKey={getItemKey}
    isSelected
/>
```

your `SelectedRowComponent` instead of `isSeleted: false` receiving `isSelected: true`. And while `true` is a valid subtype of `boolean` the type `D` was instantiaded with *different* subtype where the type of `isSelected` field is `false`. Another valid subtype of type `boolean` but not the same as `true`.

Another problem. While your component is expecting properties of type `D` you're trying to pass it properties `SelectedRowProps` of type `Partial<D>` plus `{ item: ITreeItem<T>; getItemKey: (item: T) => string | number; isSelected: true; }`. Imagine we have type `D` declared as:

```ts
interface ExtendedItemProps extends ITreeItemProps<{}> {
  title: string
}
```

Notice that `title` is required field. But you can easily supply `SelectedRowProps` without that field as `Partial` does exactly that to types.

So here is at least two things that can go wrong with type definitions like that.

There is also a minor issue with overcomplicated type `React.ComponentProps<ITreeItemRenderer<T, D>['SelectedRowComponent'] & {}>`. That is pretty complicated way to say `D`.

---

All in all if your `SelectedRowComponent` accepts exact types of `ITreeItemProps<T>` **plus** some extra props you should write your type without *extending* `ITreeItemProps` in generic way. Your `ITreeItemRenderer` may look like that for example:

```ts
export interface ITreeItemRenderer<T, D extends Record<string, any> = {}>{
    getItemKey: (item: T) => string | number; 
    SelectedRowComponent?: React.ComponentType<Omit<D, keyof ITreeItemProps<any>> & ITreeItemProps<T>>
    SelectedRowProps: D & Partial<ITreeItemProps<T>>;
    items: ITreeItem<T>[];
    selected?: string | number;
}

function TreeItemRenderer<T, D>(props: ITreeItemRenderer<T, D>) {...}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mqv6qW)

Notice that `SelectedRowProps` is **not** optional here. Otherwise you cannot get those extra properties to pass to the `SelectedRowComponent` component. Here we're essentially telling the typescript that `getItemkey`, `isSelected` and `item` fields has the exact types from `ITreeItemProps<T>` but component can accept some *extra* properties from type `D` and inside `SelectedRowProps` you should specify only those fields required in `D` but fields from `ITreeItemProps<T>` may be omitted.

---

I hope you understand that even if your `SelectedRowProps` prop has any of the fields `getItemKey`, `isSelected` or `item` set they **all** will be **overriden** by other properties from `ITreeItemRenderer` here:

```ts
<SelectedRowComponent 
    {...SelectedRowProps}
    item={item}
    getItemKey={getItemKey}
    isSelected
/>
```